# activeadmin adding datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm working with rails' activeadmin and creating a custom form like so:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, Client.find(@wedding_cake.client_id), @wedding_cake] do |f| %>
```

than I want to add an input for a date like so:

```
<%= f.input :date, as: :datepicker %>
```

However, I'm getting "Unable to find input class for datepicker" from rails.
I've tried including jquery date picker in my gem file, but that didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Combine-datetime-picker-with-activeadmin

Comment: I tried that, it didn't do anything. :/

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this exact issue and what worked for me was: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Combine-datetime-picker-with-activeadmin#or-do-it-manually

Specifically:

> In active_admin, change the column use
>
> :as => datepicker TO :as => :string, :input_html => {:class => "hasDatetimePicker"}

However, I had to prepend the datepicker class, and in my case, change `hasDatetimePicker` to `hasDatePicker`

```
:as => :string, :input_html => {:class => 'datepicker hasDatePicker'}
```

h/t to Eugen's comment for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @Silvertail, accept this guys answer. I've tested it and it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try the DateNTimePickerActiveAdmin Rubygem. It works really well and is customisable according to your project.

You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/NikhithaGraceJosh/date_n_time_picker_activeadmin

From the docs:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'date_n_time_picker_activeadmin'
```

**Code Sample (In your form)**

```
f.input :column_name, as: :datetimepicker
```

**CSS**

In active_admin.scss, add the line,

```
@import date_n_time_picker_activeadmin
```

**JS**

In active_admin.js, add the line,

```
//= require date_n_time_picker_activeadmin
```

Hope it's useful!